# Excel or VBA: 4D chart

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a 4D column chart in Excel, like in the following picture:

[image]

Could anyone please suggest a solution? (Using VBA is fine.)
A sample Excel data is shown below and the sample excel file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77YTx_frPvkakJFVmFRRXRnY0U/view?usp=sharing) (can be viewed right on the browsers).

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
Class 1 
Cat 1   Cat 2   Cat 3
A   6   9   7
B   2   5   1
C   0   6   0


Class 2 
Cat 1   Cat 2   Cat 3
A   2   5   4
B   4   5   2
C   1   5   2


Class 3 
Cat 1   Cat 2   Cat 3
A   8   0   7
B   1   2   7
C   1   6   4
```

Comment: Does Excel's [3D Chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-display-of-a-3-D-chart-60c13909-d2a1-4e06-8b8c-bccba7868c9b) option not work?

Comment: @BruceWayne Hi. Unfortunately using Excel 3D Chart I could only create clustered column bars, but not **stacked** ones as in the above picture.

Comment: What have you tried? There are a [few posts](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/130327-how-do-i-make-3d-column-graph-using-stacked-bars.html) online when you [do a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+3d+stacked+column+chart)

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes I read that already (the OP wanted to do the same thing), but there's no concrete solution proposed :( (Someone suggested John Walkenbach's book and I'll look into that).

Comment: Can you post the data? I know you linked to the file, but I (and I'm sure most others) are hesitant in downloading a file from online.

Comment: @BruceWayne Sure I have added the data, please see the update. By the way the sample file is on Google Drive so you can view it safely in your browser without downloading it. P/s: downvoters please explain your reason.

Comment: Thanks for the data.  What have you tried so far? Any code/manipulating of the data? I would guess downvotes are because there's no info. on what you've tried so far.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks. I rearranged the data and got a clustered columns but had not idea how to get the stacked one (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4yzpzC3QL6-bVJQLXI3MlNyNVk). I'm following the solution suggested in John Walkenbach's book (create three different charts and overlay them). Looks like I have found an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Create three different charts for Class 1, Class 2, Class 3 and then carefully overlay them.

Reference: Excel Charts by John Walkenbach (chapter 8, page 294).